# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException with reactive mongo repository: required a bean of type that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-bean

I have an issue: repository bean couldn't be found when it's placed in outer package. It causes nested `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` which is due to `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` (expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate).
After I copied the class to my project, it works perfectly. But I would like to use it as a dependency on external module.
This is repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Person, String> {
}
```

And classes from project that should use the repository:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("outer.package.repository")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {
        "outer.package.repository"
        //"local.package.repository" // temporary solution, should be external
})
public class MyConfig {
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PersonService {
    private final PersonRepository personRepository;
// do some stuff
}
```

As you see, I have all needed annotations on beans (`@Repository`, `@Service`, `@Configuration`), I registered mongo repositories (`@EnableMongoRepositories`) and even provided the directory to scan (`@ComponentScan`). Do you have any ideas what I've missed?

UPD: I'm using maven and project structure is like this:

```
src
  main
    java
      com
        example
          configuration
            MyConfig.java
          controller
            PersonController.java
          repository
            PersonRepository.java
          service
            PersonService.java
          MainApplication.java
    resources
  test
pom.xml
```

Comment: Are you using maven or gradle? How does your project structure look like? Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue?

Comment: Please check updated question, I added this info

Comment: You've written:  "I would like to use it as a dependency on external module".  Looking at the project structure I can't see that module. Is it a separate maven module that contains the `outer.package.repository.PersonRepository`?
Apart from the provided description, it may be easier to also provide the link to a bitbucket / github / gitlab repository which reproduces the issue

Comment: Yes, PersonRepository is from separate maven module in other project. I placed a copy of it in my project and it works. But it should be external library instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce the issue and it seems that changing the annotation

```java
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {
        "outer.package.repository"
        //"local.package.repository" // temporary solution, should be external
})
public class MyConfig {}
```

to its reactive equivalent:

```java
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories(basePackages = {
        "outer.package.repository"
        //"local.package.repository" // temporary solution, should be external
})
public class MyConfig {}
```

solved the issue.
More on that in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#mongo.reactive.repositories.usage)

> MongoDB uses two different drivers for imperative (synchronous/blocking) and reactive (non-blocking) data access. You must create a connection by using the Reactive Streams driver to provide the required infrastructure for Spring Data’s Reactive MongoDB support. **Consequently, you must provide a separate configuration for MongoDB’s Reactive Streams driver.** Note that your application operates on two different connections if you use reactive and blocking Spring Data MongoDB templates and repositories.